# Need to Scramble the selected Text

Tags: c#

```
    protected void Button_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        string[] readtext = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        var a = readtext;
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
         foreach (string s in readtext)
        {
            strList.Add(s);
        }
        ListBox1.DataSource = strList;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        var a = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (b < 0)
        {
            // no ListBox item selected;
            return;
        }

           StringBuilder jumbleSB = new StringBuilder();
            jumbleSB.Append(a);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int lengthSB = jumbleSB.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthSB; ++i)
            {
                int index1 = (rand.Next() % lengthSB);
                int index2 = (rand.Next() % lengthSB);
                Char temp = jumbleSB[index1];
                jumbleSB[index1] = jumbleSB[index2];
                jumbleSB[index2] = temp;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(jumbleSB);

            TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Text.ToString();
            //TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Text.Insert(jumbleSB);
```

Here I need to Jumble the values which selected by User. When User selects a Value it has to jumble and has to come to Textbox. I am not able to displaying the Jumble values. Any help Please...??

Comment: Are you trying to get the string out of `StringBuilder`? Like `TextBox1.Text = jumbleSB.ToString();`

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(jumbleSB.ToString());
```